# How to convert [1024]C.char to [1024]byte

Tags: go, cgo

How do I convert this C (array) type:

```
char my_buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

to this Go (array) type:

```
type buffer [C.BUF_SIZE]byte
```

? Trying to do an interface conversion gives me this error:

```
cannot convert (*_Cvar_my_buf) (type [1024]C.char) to type [1024]byte
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest and safest way is to copy it to a slice, not specifically to `[1024]byte`

```
mySlice := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(&C.my_buff), C.BUFF_SIZE)
```

To use the memory directly without a copy, you can "cast" it through an `unsafe.Pointer`.

```
mySlice := unsafe.Slice((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&C.my_buf)), C.BUFF_SIZE)
// and if you need an array type, the slice can be converted
myArray := ([C.BUFF_SIZE]byte)(mySlice)
```

Comment: I specifically want an array, not a slice. One of the reasons is that I do want to make a copy. Also, `C.BUF_SIZE` *is* a constant, so I can use it in a typedef. Also, why convert it to a pointer to a huge array?

Answer (score 1):

To create a Go slice with the contents of C.my_buf:

```
arr := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(&C.my_buf), C.BUF_SIZE)
```

To create a Go array...

```
var arr [C.BUF_SIZE]byte
copy(arr[:], C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(&C.my_buf), C.BUF_SIZE))
```

Comment: @JimB The second example seems to work for me. Here's an example https://play.golang.org/p/O49FFSyHCG (test locally) What error do you get? I'm running go1.4 on a Mac.

Comment: Ah, I never checked to see if cgo treated `DEFINE` as a constant. That does work in this case.

Comment: FYI, the second example copies the data twice.

Comment: @JimB where is the first copy? I assume the second one is done by the actual `copy` built-in. And @tidwall, why take the address of `C.by_buf[0]`? Isn't that the same as taking the address of `C.my_buf`?

Comment: @AttilaO. `C.GoBytes` makes a copy of the data into a new slice.

Comment: @JimB Oh. I was under the impression that `C.GoBytes` will return a `[]byte` that points to the underlying C array. I see now that it does indeed make a copy.

Comment: @AttilaO. There is no difference.