# How to get a void** to be a parameter of a C library?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to call a C library from GO using cgo.

The C library has the following function:

```c
int receive(void** data);

// I'd call it like that:
void* myptr; // myptr=null
int nbBytes = receive(&myptr);
if (nbBytes==0) { return }
// myptr has now an address to a valid buffer that contains nbBytes bytes.

// And then casting it with char* to access the data that can be anything. Example:
printf("%d", *(char*)myptr);
```

How can I call this `receive()` function from GO? Go doesn't allocate any memory, the memory address is returned via `myptr` and directly access from it.

- `receive()` is a "no-copy" and writes the actual data's address into `myptr`. The data is then accessed using `*(char*)myptr`.
- we can assume `receive()` allocates and frees the buffer, it's hidden from the lib's user

Ideally, I would read the data via `[]byte` in go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: you added a clarification that says this isn't just suggested.  But we still don't know how the data are used afterward, from C code.]

There is not enough information in your question to answer it completely, because we don't know—the C language alone doesn't tell us—how this `void **` is used.  Your comments and additional code *suggest* (pretty strongly) that the way it's used is that `receive` fills in the pointer:

```c
int receive(void **data) {
    *data = <something>;
    return <some value>;
}
```

where the angle-bracketed sections are unknown to us; to use this data from C code, we'd do just what you said:

```c
void f(void) {
    void *p;
    int ret;
    ...
    ret = receive(&p);
}
```

What we *don't* know, given this much and the (justifiable) assumptions, are:

- What does the `ret` value indicate?
- Is `p` always valid afterward?
- How many bytes at `*p` are accessible?

For instance, would:

```c
struct our_data dst;
memcpy(&dst, p, len);
```

be a valid way to get the bytes from `p` into the data-structure `dst`, and if so, where does the length `len` come from?  Is it implied, e.g., do we know that because `ret` was not `-1` (error) that `p` is valid and has `sizeof(struct our_data)` bytes available, and we need the memcpy just to make it properly aligned?

If we knew all of these things, we'd be able to do the job directly from Go:

```go
var p unsafe.Pointer
var obj C.struct_our_data
ret := C.receive(&p)
C.memcpy(unsafe.Pointer(&obj), p, len) // or similar with copy()
```

although it might—depending on task etc—make more sense to just write a deserializer for the raw data, which we obtain as an array living in C memory; see, e.g., [How to convert [1024]C.char to [1024]byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27532523/1256452).

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question, please comment if that's not enough.

Comment: How do you know how long the accessible data are?

Comment: yes, it's handled via a different function. My question is regarding the void** and cgo. From that `void*` I need a `[]byte`, either no-copy from the C pointer or by copying the data.

Comment: OK - see the linked question. If the length is variable, you use the "convert to giant array and then take a slice of it" method. If it's a constant, convert to an array of the right size (and then slice or not—it's up to you).

Comment: That is, we'll use the `mySlice := (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&C.my_buf))[:int(C.BUFF_SIZE):int(C.BUFF_SIZE)]` but instead of `unsafe.Pointer(&var)` you already just have `p`. The `[1 << 30]` just has to be "at least as big as the actual length".